# Frobenius norm of $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Find the Frobenius norm of the following $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ matrix: 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    2 & 1 & 0 &  0\dots 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \dots 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \dots 0 \\
    \vdots & &\ddots & \\
    0 & \ldots & 1 & 2
    \end{bmatrix}

The Frobenius norm is the sum of squares of each element and then square root:
I think it should be $\sqrt{n\cdot 2^2 + (n-1)\cdot 1 + (n-1) \cdot 1} $ since we have $n$ $2$s in the diagonal, and in the super and sub-diagonal we have $n-1$ $1$s. In total it is: $$\sqrt{4n+2n-2}= \sqrt{6n-2}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Your matrix isn't square.

Comment: @pyon what do you mean?

Comment: It is not square, hence not $n \times n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times n}$ has $n-1$ entries $(A)_{jj}=1$ for $j=1,...,n-1$ and $n-1$ entries $(A)_{j(j+1)}=2$  for $j=1,...,n-1$ and $n-2$ entries $(A)_{j(j+2)}=1$ for $j=1,...,n-2$. All other entries are zero and thus its Frobenius-norm is
$$||A||_F=\sqrt{(n-1)1^2+(n-1)2^2+(n-2)1^2}=\sqrt{6n-7}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I did not write my matrix correctly. Is it okay now?

Comment: If You mean the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with entries $(A)_{(j+1)j}=(A)_{j(j+1)}=1$ for $j=1,...,n-1$ and $(A)_{jj}=2$ for $j=1,...,n$ and all other entries zero thats OK! (It looks a little bit different though)

Comment: I don't know if I wrote it correctly, but that is what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You´re welcome!